# pdo_sqlsrv and date format with Laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, laravel, laravel-4

I wanted to try [Laravel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel) for a while, so I spent the afternoon setting it up.

On Windows I installed: [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) 32-bit with PHP 5.4, [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) 3.0 drivers from Microsoft (that's why I use WAMP 32 bit) and Composer.

Then I created a project, download Laravel and generators. I created a scaffold to see the kind of code it generates and test it.

My first "create" action failed because of a nvarchar to datetime conversion error. I pasted the query in [SQL Server Management Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) (SSMS) and fire it with same results.

The mistake comes from the date format. Laravel put it this way: "2013-12-17 16:55:124". But before the request, it sends some set to SQL Server, and one is very interesting:

```
set dateformat dmy
```

To me `set dateformat dmy` means it expects a date like this:
"17-12-2013 16:55:124"

In SSMS changing the set dateformat to:

```
set dateformat ymd
```

or changing the date format in the request makes it works.

I don't think it is a bug. I just think something is misconfigured. I just don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way around which seems quite clean. The trick is to force Laravel to use `datetime2` instead of `datetime` with SQL Server.

In order to do this you need to do those changes:

In Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/SqlServerGrammar.php

```
protected function typeDateTime(Fluent $column)
{
    return 'datetime'; // Change to datetime2
}
```

And

```
protected function typeTimestamp(Fluent $column)
{
    return 'datetime'; // Change to datetime2
}
```

Then in Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/SqlServerGrammar.php:

```
public function getDateFormat()
{
    return 'Y-m-d H:i:s.000'; // change to 'Y-m-d H:i:s.0000000'
}
```

I hope it helps someone...

Comment: Hello I agree with you but my answer is 4 years old and problem was on Laravel 4. Plus i did a PR on laravel so it got fixed long time ago

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using DB::raw wit SQL's server specific syntax for datetime.

```
public function datetime() {

    $addDate = DB::insert("insert into TABLE (date) values (convert(date,'$date',127))");

}
```

I don't know exactly why it happens, but the same function with classic Laravel DB syntax return SQLSTATE[22007].

```
public function datetime() {

    $addDate = DB::table('TABLE')
    ->insert([
        'date'=> $date]);

   // return SQLSTATE[22007]
}
```